# Visual Studio 2022 section markers

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just updated VS 2022 this morning and found a text editor change I don't like.

How can I change this:

[image]

Back to this:

[image]

A search for an answer did not find any results. I searched for "visual studio 2022 change caret back to plus sign" and variations of that. It's likely too new of a change for anyone to have posted a question and answer yet.  Thanks in advance